# Código Java Ponto2D, nao exibe a distancia corretamente

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

```
package OrientacaoObjetos;

public class Ponto2D {
    //campos publicos: nao existem restricoes p/ valores de x e y
    public double x, y;

    //constr. default: ponto definido na origem(0, 0)
    public Ponto2D() {
        x = 0; y = 0;
    }
    //constr. paramentizada: ponto definido na instanciacao
    public Ponto2D(double px, double py) {
        x = px; y = py;
    }
    //determina distancia entre instancia e cordenada dada
    public double distancia(double px, double py) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x- px, 2) + Math.pow(y- py, 2));
    }
    //determina distancia entre instancia e cordenada dada
   public double distancia(Ponto2D p) {
       return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x- p.x, 2) + Math.pow(y- p.y, 2));
   }
   //fornece representacao textual dos objetos
   public String toString() {
       return "Ponto2D[x=" + x + ",y=" + y + "]";
   }
}
```

Aqui eu defino valores para px e py na criação de um novo objeto Ponto2D.
coloco uma distancia e ele exibe apenas os valores px e py dados na criação do Ponto2D construtor.

```
package OrientacaoObjetos;

public class UsaPonto2D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ponto2D p1 = new Ponto2D(3.3, 4.6);
        p1.distancia(55.5, 32.1);
        System.out.println(p1.toString());
    }

}
```

O que há de errado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algumas coisas estão erradas:

### 1 - Você calcula a distância mas não a armazena em lugar algum.

Ao fazer a chamada `p1.distancia(55.5, 32.1);`, você executa o método `distancia` mas simplesmente ignora seu retorno. O ideal é você armazenar o que essa função te devolve (retorno) para usar posteriormente. Por exemplo:

```
double dist = p1.distancia(55.5, 32.1);
```

### 2 - Você só imprime o ponto `p1`.

Ao fazer a chamada `System.out.println(p1.toString());` você está somente imprimindo o conteúdo do seu objeto *ponto*. Vide o método `toString` pra perceber o que ele imprime. Você pode adicionar na sua classe principal uma chamada pra imprimir a distância, previamente armazenada (no meu exemplo, na variável `dist`):

```
System.out.println(p1.toString());
System.out.println("Distancia: " + dist); // Nova linha adicionada
```

Ou, alternativamente, você pode imprimir diretamente a distância sem ter um armazenamento temporário e intermediário (isto é, ignorando o "erro" 1). Por exemplo:

```
System.out.println(p1.toString());
System.out.println(p1.distancia(55.5, 32.1)); // Nova linha adicionada
```

Comment: E o que significa o 2 aqui: Math.pow(y- py, 2));

Comment: Meu caro, este site não é um fórum, e sim um site de perguntas e respostas. A sua nova dúvida é bacana, mas eu sugiro que você abra outra pergunta com ela. :) Ah, e se ainda não o fez, por favor faça o [tour] e leia a [help].

Comment: Eu só queria entender como calcular isso, para comparar com o resultado.

Comment: Sem problemas. É só você abrir outra pergunta com a nova dúvida que vai ter toda uma comunidade disposta a te ajudar (além de mim). Outra razão pra vc abrir uma nova pergunta é que uma explicação decente vai ficar grande demais pro espaço de comentários. E sério mesmo: faça ao menos o [tour] que você vai entender melhor como esse site funciona e vai se sentir mais confortável com as suas interações. :)